# Turning on dbg tracing on a remote node?

Tags: erlang

When running our Erlang application in our system tests, I sometimes want to turn on and capture a debug trace.

The Erlang node is started using a **relx** start script (called as `_rel/bin/foo foreground`), so I don't have any control over the startup options. The system test runner (written in Python) is capturing stdout from the node.

How do I connect to an Erlang node, using `-remsh`, turn on `dbg`-tracing, and have that output written to stdout on the original node? And how do I do this all in a Python-friendly way (though I'm happy to write an escript if that'll make it easier).

To complicate this further, the **relx** generated release doesn't include the `runtime_tools` library, so `dbg:` isn't actually available, so I'll also add [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22996117/8446).

Answer (score 1):

There are quite few way you could do that. All depends on what you are familiar with, and what your use case is.

- I would start from doing everything *by hand*. That way you have greatest control on that's going one, and how effects look like (if you are turning too much debugging or not enough). That's I'm most familiar with, and in the end you almost always will have to connect to remote shell and do something by hand (from my experience)
- One feature of `dbg` that not too many people talk about i ability of saving/loading trace pasterns from files. I find those easiest way to store and share debugging information in between sessions; but lack of readability might be too big trade-off.
- You don't have to use `dbg` if you don't want to interfere with your live system too much. You could use `erlang:trace` which is given by default, but you must be cautious about state you leave your VM in (`dbg` should turn off all tracing upon exit; with `erlang:trace` that's your responsibility)
- If you debug session is part of python script, writng escript and calling it from python would be my way to go.  You just have to remember that escripts are run in new VM, and `-remsh` will **not** allow you to just run your code on other VM. You will have to use `rpc` module for that.
- Since you are using application is released you might look into logging. One might assume that there should already be some logging in place, quite possible [lager](https://github.com/basho/lager) which is somewhat standard in Erlang, and which have possibility to [change logging level during runtime](https://github.com/basho/lager#runtime-loglevel-changes).

Personally I would try some mix of first and last option, and just experiment.

Comment: We're already using lager for the mundane logging; for this particular failing test, I'd like to get a trace of every called function in my modules. This is not in production, so I'm not bothered about performance impact.