# How do I modify the code search path for a remote Erlang node?

Tags: erlang

I'm connected to an Erlang node with `-remsh`. How do I modify the code path, in order to load a library that wasn't packaged into my release?

Comment: It turns out that `-remsh` doesn't create a new node, so there is no "remote" node. This doesn't help me with my real problem, but I'll leave this here anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All necessary functions to manipulate code loading, path... are in the code module (see doc at [erlang otp code module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#add_path-1)).

You could add the system paths to the list by doing the following:

```
[code:add_pathz(P) || P <- filelib:wildcard("/usr/lib/erlang/lib/*/ebin")].
```

Comment: I was getting confused. Hadn't fully internalised the fact that a remote shell is NOT a new node, so there's no question about where the code will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

After compiling some test code and connecting to a running node I was able to make it work with this:

```
(app@127.0.0.1)1> code:add_pathz("/path/to/my/compiled/beam").
(app@127.0.0.1)2> tester:hi().
hi!
ok
(app@127.0.0.1)3>
```